# SqlDependency.Start() error: "Cannot find the specified user 'owner'"

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr, sqldependency

I am trying to develop a website using Signalr and `SqlDependency`. I've enabled Service Broker and ran following T SQL:

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [SqlUser];
GRANT CREATE SERVICE TO [SqlUser];
GRANT CREATE QUEUE TO [SqlUser];
GRANT REFERENCES ON CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] TO [SqlUser];
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [SqlUser];
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [SqlUser];
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::DBO TO [SqlUser];
```

But when I run the website, I get the following error:

> Cannot find the specified user 'owner'.
>       Cannot find the queue 'SqlQueryNotificationService-ce08361b-7c12-412a-a087-495959118214', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>       Invalid object name 'SqlQueryNotificationService-ce08361b-7c12-412a-a087-495959118214'.

```
protected void Application_Start()  
{
    SqlDependency.Start(
        ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["CiaosConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Can someone help me find the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [SqlUser];
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::DBO TO [SqlUser];
```

which doesn't seem like a great idea anyway, I've found that you can get rid of that error by creating a schema owned by the user and setting that schema as the default. For example, for an existing user:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [SqlUser] AUTHORIZATION [SqlUser]
GO
ALTER USER [SqlUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [SqlUser]
```

The queues and stored procedures would be created under that schema during `SqlDependency.Start`.

Personally, I've had difficulty getting it to work using a schema owned by someone else, but I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you! The DB admin grant my user as public user so i dont have permisson to alter DB or user. Dont have anything. I try to create other user then use that user to run command. Lucky that it's sucessfull and now i can use signalr. Maybe i nerver user this hosting provider again!